# Big O sum of integers runtime

Tags: algorithm, big-o

I have am trying to learn Big O and am confused on an algorithm I just came across.  The algorithm is:

```
void pairs(int[] array){
  for (int i=0; i < array.length; i++){
    for (int j=i+1; j<array.length; j++){
      System.out.println(array[i]+","+array[j]);
    }
  }
}
```

I think the first for loop is `O(n)` and I know the second for loop is `O(1/2*n(n+1))`.  The answer to the problem was that the run time for the function is `O(n^2)`.  I simplified `O(1/2*n(n+1))` to `O(1/2*(n^2+n))`.  So I'm confused because I thought that you needed to multiply the two run time terms since the for loop is nested, which would give `O(n) * O(1/2*(n^2+n))`. I simplified this to `O(1/2n^3 + 1/2n^2)`. From what I understand of Big O, you only keep the largest term so this would reduce to `O(n^3)`.  Can anyone help me out with where I went wrong? Not sure how the answer is `O(n^2)` instead of `O(n^3)`.

Comment: That's not valid Python code.

Comment: @BrenBarn yes, I butchered that one. I put it back up in Java.

Comment: Why do you think the second loop is 1/2*n(n+1)?

Comment: @BrenBarn first run through j does n-1 steps, then n-2, then n-3, etc.  So that looks like (n-1)+(n-2)+(n-3)+...+2+1.  The sum of integers 1 through n-1 is 1/2*n*(n+1).  I think. My math is a little rusty

Comment: If you already considered all the runs from the outer loop, why are you multiplying with `O(n)` again?

Comment: @BrenBarn I didn't already consider all of the runs... the outer loop run time is O(n)

Comment: *"first run through `j` does `n-1` steps"*. First run of how many? And also *"The sum of integers `1` through `n-1`"* - where does this sequence come from?

Comment: @kdubs: When you say the inner loop is `O(1/2*n(n+1))`, you are actually describing the big-O complexity of *both* loops.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you say the inner loop is `O(1/2*n(n+1))`, you are actually describing the big-O complexity of *both* loops.

To say that the outer loop has complexity O(N) basically means its body runs N times.  But for your calculation of the inner loop's complexity, you already took account of *all* iterations of the outer loop, because you added up the number of times the inner loop runs over all iterations of the outer loop.  If you multiply again by N, you would be saying that the outer loop itself is re-run another N times.

Put another way, what your analysis shows is that the inner loop body (the `System.out.println` call) runs `1/2*n(n+1)` times overall.  That means the overall complexity of the two-loop combination is `O(1/2*n(n+1)) = O(n^2)`.  The overall complexity of the two-loop combination describes how many times the innermost code is run.

Answer (score 0):

your mistake is counting the second loop as `O(1/2n^2)`...
first, you can clearly see it is capped to `N-1` (when j = 0)

first loop is clearly `N`
Second loop is MAX of `N-1`...
threrefore, O(N^2)...

if we examine it little more,
second loop will run `N-1` when `i=0`,
then `N-2` for `i=1`,
and ONE single time for `i=n-1`,

this is `1/2n(n-1)` = `1/2n^2 - 1/2n` = `O(n^2)`
**Notice** this includes all iteration of the outer loop too!